# Best practices to expose type class instances in Scala libraries

Tags: scala, typeclass

It seems modern Scala libraries have some general pattern for exposing type class instances, I'm wondering if there's any formal spec out there or if someone could detail out what the idea is. Ideally, instances should be optional and the user should be able to supply instances or bring them in with the minimal amount of orphan instance or import tax overhead.

Answer (score 1):

if the library supports [export-hook](https://github.com/milessabin/export-hook), that's an obviously good way to go about things.

Otherwise, I think you're stuck either creating a `trait` with orphaned typeclass instances you can mixin where you need them, or just stick them in an `object` to import at will.

I suppose it's probably possible to stick them in a package object and have them in scope of anything downstream, but I dislike package objects as a general rule due to their fickle nature.

So the short answer is: if the OG library doesn't support export-hook, you gotta pay the import tax in some form or another.

Comment: To clarify, I'm mostly asking about how a library should implement its type classes and instances, not how to use them from a user perspective. The original question wasn't very clear about this, so I've attempted to reword it accordingly.